# zf2 repopulate form with filtered values

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I moved a few weeks ago from zf1 to zf2 and when I am creating forms I am getting confused.
Is there an option that values from form after being filtered going to repopulate form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is this:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($request->isPost()) {
    $form->setData($request->getPost()); 

    if ($form->isValid()) {  
          $filteredData = $form->getData();

    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that when form is invalid I cannot see filtered data.

Comment: On that case get the values from the request.

Comment: But they would be filtered data. Filtering of the values if I understand zf2 correctly is happening on isValid method. So then data which I will show back to the user if form isn't valid, wouldn't be the same as data form used to do validation.

Comment: Well the logic is, if is valid then you can save and do whatever you want if is not valid you just need to display an error message, you shouldn't be using the data if is not valid. Otherwise, remove the validation and only do the filtering. Or actually what you could do is set the validator latter, so first you get the value of the form without setting the validator and then you set the validator and you check if is valid. That should work.

Comment: Example for my case is if you have a int filter and is required on the field and user will input letters only to the field. So on the validation error message for that will be that field is required and cannot be empty. And because I set data on the form from post field wouldn't be empty. This might be a bit confused to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($request->isPost()) {
    $form->setData($request->getPost()); //Repopulate the $form object with $_POST values

    if ($form->isValid()) {   //Data is filtered here
          //code to save data
    }
}
```